# GSM ACM8060 gives error when using AT cmds in terminal but works with a cell phone

Tags: tcp, sms, command, gsm, at-command

I am using a GSM module ACM8060.
When I try to send SMS using AT commands it returns ERROR but when sms sent from a cell phone using the same SIM it sends successfully.

```
+CREG: 3
AT+CMGS="nnnnnnnnnn"

ERROR
AT+CREG?

+CREG: 1,3

OK
AT+CMGF=0

OK
AT+CMGF=1

OK
AT+CMGS="nnnnnnnnnn"

> hello [pressed ctrlZ here]
ERROR
```

where nnnnnnnnnn is a 10 digit mobile phone no.

Which setting in the module could be wrongly set. It was working earlier.

And similar in case of TCP at AT+AIPA=1 it is giving `ERROR: 301`. Again it works with a cell phone. **Which setting to look for?**

Answer (score 1):

I suggest turning on verbose error codes using `ATV1` so you get more information than simply `ERROR`. You should then receive an error code like `+CME ERROR: xxx` or `+CMS ERROR: xxx` where the xxx will be a detailed error code.

Comment: +1 sometimes AT+CMEE=1 is required to enable this on the ME also

Comment: I tried "Extended error report +CEER" I got: +CEER: "Cause Select:67 Cause:16".. tried AT+CMEE=1 returns same "ERROR" only. I only typed it in to the Terminal .. thats it right? Same output with ATV1. Am I missing something? (Same in both the cases SMS as well as TCP)

Comment: I observed that the signal below around 15 (+CSQ n,99 where max is 31) doesn't work for SMS or TCP. Now same thing works when it is 25 .. I also tried factory setting default which seems to work .. but can't say for sure.